# Free dynamic memory getting error

Tags: c, pointers, memory, free

I am having a problem of freeing dynamic memory. I have run other guy's example code, and it worked. The point is we used same way to free memory, but mine didn't work. It always comes out a error that

> "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer. "

Could anyone help me understand what happened?

```
void pop(Stackptr *ptr){
    Stackptr tmp = NULL;
    if(*ptr == NULL){
        printf("there is no element\n");
    }else{
        tmp = *ptr;
        *ptr= (*ptr)->nextptr;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Stackptr tmp` should be `Stackptr *tmp` and `*ptr == NULL` should be `ptr == NULL`. Your other pointers have a similar mistake.

Comment: Your question lack context. What is `Stackptr`? Where does `ptr` come from? Etc... The correctness of the posted code depends entirely on the rest of the code. In other word one could say that your problem is not localized to the posted code.

Answer (score 4):

As I can see, the error is

```
 tmp = *ptr;
```

You want the pointer itself to be stored int `tmp`, not the *value.*

Thus, the next `free(tmp);` becomes illegal, as the pointer you're passing is *invalid*. Calling `free()` on a pointer that is not previously returned by `malloc()` and family or already `free()`-d, invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, `if(*ptr == NULL)` should be `if(ptr == NULL)`, to check the NULL-value of the pointer.

Moral of the story: Enable compiler warnings. Try to fix the issues for which your compiler issues a warning.